# React: How to Stop iframe video from playing when Bootstrap Modal is closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I got a button that opens a bootstrap modal with a `iframe` element containing a youtube video, but when I close down the modal the video keeps playing, how do I get it to stop playing when the modal is closed?

**Button to open modal:**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#" className="btn btn-
rounded btn-sm btn-primary"><i className="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> Open Modal</a>
```

**My react component with a modal containing the `iframe` video**

```
class Modal extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
    }

 render() {
    return (
     <div id="myModal" className="modal fade">
        <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 className="modal-title">YouTube Video</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <iframe id="cartoonVideo" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k" frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
}
```

How would I make the video stop playing when I close down the modal inside a react component?

Comment: Why are you using iframe ? you can use react component for that. like this one for ex: https://github.com/troybetz/react-youtube or https://github.com/souporserious/react-media-player

Comment: Its because I am going to use videos from alot of different providers besides youtube, and iframe seems to be the only solution that can play all the other providers i'v tried. If that makes sense :)

Comment: It is not the right solution. You can build your own React component to handle this or look at one of above mentioned players. the last one enables you to provide your own video URLs. demo here https://souporserious.github.io/react-media-player/

Comment: I have already tried that component, but unfortunately its not compatible with plays.tv that i really need to implement. But there is no way to maybe use jquery to force iframe to stop playing?

Comment: use react bootstrap, by using classnames you are only hiding the modal, not closing it.